# This JQuery works in Chrome and Safari, Not FF?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a bunch of code that will open and close a div using the slidetoggle/toggleclass method

Now while the DIv is opened, I added in this little bit to allow the window to close if someone clicks outside of the now opened div.

```
$("body").live("click", function() {
    if($(event.target).parents().index($('.subpanel')) == -1) 
    {
        if($('.subpanel').is(":visible"))
        {
            $(".alerts").toggleClass("notiftitleactive");
            $(".alerts").toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(50);
            $("body").die("click");
        }
    }  
});
```

This works perfectly well in google chome and safari.  But in firefox, clicking outside of the div does nothing (does not trigger the .alerts to toggleclass/slidetoggle).

Any idea why this wouldnt work in FF ?

Thanks!

Comment: $("body").live("click", function() { ... } Don't have a "event" param?
$("body").live("click", function(event) { ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using either

```
$(document).click(function(){...});
```

or

```
$(window).click(function(){...});
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Try doing a regular click event rather than a live event.

Comment: now clicking *inside* of the opened div makes it quickly flash open and close